# Rails Active Admin Modify Default Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have an Rails app and I'm using Active Admin (0.3.1) as mi admin interface. The thing is I want to add a new model to it, but I need to do insert some custom code on the create action after the user submits the form.

is it possible? How it's done?

I need to process some data and create some other objects in the create process.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: A Bit late, but do you know it is possible to define observers that take action when a certain model gets saved. You may want to check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers      (dont forget to register the observers too :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify the ActiveAdmin controller, you could do it like this:

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Post do

      controller do
        # This code is evaluated within the controller class

        def create
          # override the action here
        end
      end

    end
```

Comment: don't forget ``create!`` at the end of method

Comment: Can you provide an example? Getting an Missing Template error when doing this kind of create.